# DAX Divide using value based on another boolean column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a measure SHARE that will return the division between value from the column SUM and SUM_SALES.
But the catch is that the measure should use only the SUM value for which Primary column has the value == true.

All of these should be happening within the filter context, and the filter will be applied on the column KEY which comes from the other table.

Desired output:

| KEY | PRIMARY | SALES | SUM_SALES | SHARE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | 10 | 20 | 0.5 |
| 1 | false | 2 | 20 | 0.5 |
| 1 | false | 3 | 20 | 0.5 |
| 2 | false | 15 | 100 | 0.8 |
| 2 | false | 5 | 100 | 0.8 |
| 2 | ture | 80 | 100 | 0.8 |

In other words, the measure SHARE should calculate the division between the value of SALES for which the PRIMARY column is true and SUM_SALES. The results should be the same for the all the rows in SHARE withing the filter context.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SHARE =
CALCULATE ( [SALES] / [SUM_SALES], Table1[PRIMARY] = "true" )
```

Comment: That doeasn work, this formula adds additional rows with different primary flag, and is still not filling the row where primary = false :/